# NoReverseMatch at /music/ beginner to Django

Tags: django, django-models

Was trying to create model forms for updating and deleting instances of album- the DB element, by following the Bucky Roberts: Django Tutorial for Beginners.

index.html is the following

```html
{% extends 'music/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Playspa{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <form id="form_uord" method="post" >
      <ol>
        {% for album in object_list %} <!-- object_list is the default
          where the data returned by the view is stored in the html script -->
        <li>
          <a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}">{{ album.album_title}}</a>
          &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
          <!--<a href="{% url 'music:album-update' album.id %}" > update </a>-->
          <button id="update_button" type="button" value="update" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="upd()"> update</button>
          &nbsp &nbsp
          <!--<a href="{% url 'music:album-delete' album.id %}" >delete</a>-->
          <button id="delete_button" type="button" value="delete" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="del()">delete</button></br></br>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ol>
    </form>
    <script>

      function upd()
      {
        var f= document.getElementById("form_uord");
        f.action="{% url 'music:album-update' album.id %}";
        var but=document.getElementById("update_button");
        but.type="submit";
        but.submit();
      }
      function del()
      {
        var f= document.getElementById("form_uord");
        f.action="{% url 'music:album-delete' album.id %}";
        var but=document.getElementById("update_button");
        but.type="submit";
        but.submit();
      }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

following are the urls in the app urls.py file

```
url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),

#music/register
url(r'^register/$', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='register'),

# /music/71/
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),

#music/album/add/
url(r'album/add/$', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name='album-add'),

#/music/album/2/
url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.AlbumUpdate.as_view(), name='album-update'),

#/music/album/2/delete/
url(r'album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$',views.AlbumDelete.as_view(), name='album-delete'),
```

Given below is the views.py file

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Album
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import UserForm

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name= 'music/index.html'
    #context_object_name= 'all_albums' this var is set when the default
    #object_list name has to be changed for list returned by

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model= Album
    template_name= 'music/detail.html'


class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model=Album
    fields=['artist','album_title','genre','album_logo']

class AlbumUpdate(UpdateView):
    model=Album
    fields=['artist','album_title','genre','album_logo']

class AlbumDelete(DeleteView):
    model=Album
    success_url= reverse_lazy('music:index')

class UserFormView(View):
    form_class= UserForm
    template_name= 'music/registration_form.html'

    def get(self, request): #display blank form for registration
        form= self.form_class(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form= self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user= form.save(commit=False)

            username= form.cleaned_data['username']
            password= form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            #returns user obj if login creds are correct
            user= authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('music:index')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

The terminal meanwhile read the following .

```
Internal Server Error: /music/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
response = response.render()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 84, in rendered_content
content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 458, in render
url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'album-update' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'music/album/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
[31/May/2018 06:09:23] "GET /music/ HTTP/1.1" 500 161922
```

I am stuck at this point because changing the update and delete triggers from hyperlinks to buttons broke the code and being a newbie I am unable to get help myself.

Comment: Obviously `album.id` is empty, probably because `album` is `None`. Post your view code that uses that `index.html` template.

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of things wrong here, but the immediate error is that `album` is not defined within your JS script; is only defined within the loop earlier. Instead of using the `url` tag in the JS, you should do it in the loop and pass it to the function on click.

Comment: thanks for insight into the mistake. However, is the **url**  tag in the js not being passed as a simple string ; which can then later, in the backend be interpreted as **album**

Comment: I don't understand your comment. The url tag cannot be resolved, because the "album" variable is not available at that point.

Comment: thanks. One more thing though, is the way in which Im changing the type of button and submitting the button from JS correct?